# Inverse of Sum of Matrix Inverses

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Given $N$ positive-definite matrices $\Lambda_i$,
I need to efficiently compute $\Gamma_N$, where
$$ \Gamma_n = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \Lambda_i^{-1}\right)^{-1}. $$
Applying the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) gives a recurrence relation
$$ \Gamma_n = \Gamma_{n-1} - \Gamma_{n-1} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \Lambda_i\right)^{-1} \Gamma_{n-1},  $$
but directly implementing this method would require $N-1$ matrix inversions (or  Cholesky decompositions) to compute $\Gamma_N$.

Is there a cleverer way to compute $\Gamma_N$ that is both computationally efficient and numerically stable?

Comment: Minor point - surely it requires $N-1$ inversions to compute $\Gamma_{N}$? You get $\Gamma_{1}$ for free then need one inversion for each of $\Gamma_{2}$ to $\Gamma_{n}$. (I really wanted to add something more useful, but I couldn't think of anything after thinking about it for half an hour. I'm interested to see if there is a better way of doing it.)

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'll claim that I originally meant $O(N)$ inversions. ;-)